# What is the best way to handle 'Too many entity kinds' and 'Too many inflight exports' when exporting from Google Datastore to a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, export, google-cloud-datastore, bucket

I am using Google Cloud's export script

> https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export

to export a list of kinds to bucket but running into this problem:

> 'Too many entity kinds'

and

> 'Too many inflight exports'

Answer (score 1):

That kind of problems are usually related to quota:

> The managed export and import service limits the number of concurrent
> exports and imports to 50 and allows a maximum of 20 export and import
> requests per minute for a project.[[1]](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities)

1.- https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities